# JsonConvert.DeserializeObject array of arrays

Tags: json.net, json-deserialization

This is similar to other postings, but my variation is that my json object begins as an array of arrays, and I can't get it to deserialize.

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var json = @"[[{""f1"":1, ""f2"":2}]]";
        var obj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject[]>(json);
    }
}

public class RootObject
{
    public List<InnerObject> InnerObjects { get; set; } 
}

public class InnerObject
{
    public int f1 { get; set; }
    public int f2 { get; set; }
}
```

I've also tried

```
JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<RootObject>>(json);
```

and various other variations.  The exception text begins "Cannot deserialize the current JSON array (e.g. [1,2,3]) into type 'jsontest.RootObject' because the type requires a JSON object (e.g. {"name":"value"}) to deserialize correctly."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your JSON corresponds to a `List<List<InnerObject>>` not a `RootObject[]`.  (For the latter, the JSON would need to look like this: `[{ "InnerObjects" : [{"f1": 1, "f2": 2}] }]`).

Try deserializing like this:

```
var list = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<List<InnerObject>>>(json);
```

Fiddle: https://dotnetfiddle.net/ELnmfg